# Traversing object structure

Tags: python, oop, object

I was investigating a memory leak and I was looking for a way to traverse an object. I came up with the following code.

```
def obj_scan(obj, path, fname):
    def _store(msg):
        open(fname, 'a').write(path+msg+'\n')

    try:
        if callable(obj):
            return
        obj_type = type(obj)
        if obj_type is str:
            _store('- STR {}'.format(len(obj)))
        elif obj is None:
            _store('- NONE')
        elif obj_type is int:
            _store('- INT')
        elif obj_type is list:
            for idx, val in enumerate(obj):
                obj_scan(val, '{}[{}]'.format(path, idx), fname)
        elif obj_type is dict:
            for key, val in obj.iteritems():
                fmt_line = '{}['+('"{}"]' if type(key) is str else ']')
                obj_scan(val, fmt_line.format(path, key), fname)
        else:
            for attr in dir(obj):
                if ('.'+attr) in path and attr != '__dict__':
                    count = path.count('.'+attr)+1
                    _store('.{} - ATTR repeated {}{}'.format(attr, count, ' - BACTRACKING'*(count>10)))
                    if count>10:
                        return
                obj_scan(getattr(obj, attr), '{}.{}'.format(path, attr), fname)
    except Exception as msg:
        _store('Recursion limit exceeded')
```

My question is - is there a more efficient way to do this? (I know - output won't win a beauty contest)

Comment: Probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And using `repr()` for keys, and using [`collections` Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) to ducktype sequences and mappings.

Comment: If you want catch recursion-limit errors you should catch `RuntimeError` and not `Exception`. Anyway I would split that function into more functions: one for every object "type", one that knows how to determine the "type" and the last one that given the type calls the correct function(which can be done using a `dict`). In this way it should be easier to extend afterwards to include more types.